# XCode 4.5: xcodeindex command line tool

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

Apparently there was a tool called xcodeindex in earlier XCode versions to index projects from the command line. However there doesn't seem to be one even after I install the command line tools in Preferences.

**Am I just not finding it? Is there any other way to force indexing a projects?**

(The problem is that If I download a project from for example SVN and try to do an xcodebuild on it without opening it in XCode first it will fail with a message like the specified scheme does not exist in the project. If I open it in XCode first and let it index a little, xcodebuild will not fail.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: there is no need to index the project. By going into the "Manage Schemes" menu in XCode and checking the "**shared**" checkbox next to the particular scheme, the problem will be solved.